# How to create a function for a dataframe with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, function

I have this data frame of clients purchases and I would like to create a function that gave me the total purchases for a given input of month and year.

I have a dataframe (df) with lots of columns but i'm going to use only 3 ("year", "month", "value")

This is what I'm trying but not working:

```
def total_purchases():
    y = input('Which year do you want to consult?')
    m = int(input('Which month do you want to consult?')
    sum = []
    if df[df['year']== y] & df[df['month']== m]:
       for i in df:
         sum = sum + df[df['value']]
    return sum
```

Answer (score 3):

You're close, you need to ditch the IF statement and the For loop.

additionally, when dealing with multiple logical operators in pandas you need to use parenthesis to seperate the conditions.

```
def total_purchases(df):
    y = input('Which year do you want to consult? ')
    m = int(input('Which month do you want to consult? '))
    return df[(df['year'].eq(y)) & (df['month'].eq(m))]['value'].sum()
```

## setup

```
df_p = pd.DataFrame({'year' : ['2011','2011','2012','2013'],
                  'month' : [1,2,1,2],
                  'value' : [200,500,700,900]})
```

## Test

```
total_purchases(df_p)

Which year do you want to consult? 2011
Which month do you want to consult? 2

500
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But mine is returning 0, idk why.... My data types are the same as yours

Comment: it returns 0 from the example above or on your own dataframe? if you have strings, inspect them there may be white space @ViniciusGushiken